# Printing in Flex Mobile Applications (Flash builder 4.7)

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, printing

I was hoping to find an easy way to print PDFs that display from my flex developed mobile iphone app.

Doesn't look like Adobe has made this available on Air.

At this point, is there any way to print anything from a flex mobile app?  Print screen or print bitmap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. It is not available through the AIR SDK in any shape or form on mobile (as of 3.7, anyway).

However, you can create an AIR Native Extension (a code base written in Objective-C or Java, depending on platform that connects through an AS3 library) that can do this. On my last project, we tasked one of our iOS devs to create an extension that allowed for the native "Open In" and "Sharing" menus to display and interact with data in an AIR app. Along with that share menu came the option to Print, depending on content.  It worked great and did exactly as we had hoped. I am sure you could build one that only did this with the print menu and did not do the full Share menu if needed.

I will warn you, however, that native extensions are not easy to create by any means. It involves knowing a separate language, using poorly documented libraries from Adobe, and command line work. Additionally, an iOS ANE **must** be created on OS X in XCode. There is no way (that I know of, at least) to create it in Windows or Linux.